# How to enable log in dompdf?

Tags: php, error-logging, dompdf

I generating PDF files using dompdf in my PHP application.
Here is the code:

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");   
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("XXX.pdf");
return $dompdf;
?>
```

When I click the download button; PDF tries to download but finally it throws an error

> C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\xxx.pdf.part could not be saved, because the source file could not be read.
>   Try again later, or contact the server administrator.

Now I want to file the error log in dompdf library file.  Can anyone help me how to create log in log.htm file?  Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sankar.

Comment: This seems to be more of a browser error. You'll need to track down the server side problem. I see you've tried enabling error logging. As a last resort you can try telling PHP to send errors to the browser. Also, you might try capturing to a string ($pdf = $dompdf->outout()) then saving to a file. That way you can at least see if the PDF is rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, the try catch does not seem to catch the error.

I would open the corrupt PDF in a text editor - in my case what I saw were errors reported

`Warning: mb_convert_encoding():`

That should give you a clue about how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are seeing does not exist in the [current source code](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) of dompdf.

Looking through other errors seems to reveal that they're *almost always* [exceptions](http://php.net/language.exceptions).

Therefore, if you want to capture the error and log it, you should just be able to wrap it in a try block, similar to this:

```
require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");   
try {
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("XXX.pdf");
    return $dompdf;
} catch(Exception $e) {
// Do something here with $e and notify the user of the error in whatever way you see fit
}
```

If this isn't grabbing the error you're experiencing, make sure you're using the latest version.  If that still doesn't help, then that error is coming from somewhere else entirely and you'll need to search elsewhere for it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  I dont get any error even when I enabled PHP error.  When I compared my local file with server file; it shows the server file does not have the PDF ending object.  I have no idea about this.